# Behavior of the Kernel under high memory load

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, scheduling, resource-scheduling

I have observed the following behavior under Ubuntu 12.04:

On a system with 24GB of RAM and 24 CPUs, if a single process acquires ~12GB of RAM, all other processes belonging to the owner of the high memory process are killed without warning, using what appears to be SIGKILL, and the high memory process is allowed to run until termination. Additionally, attempts to start new processes by the owner will fail.

This is a bit bothersome, but I'm more curious as to why it happens. Presumably this is the result of a resource scheduling decision in the kernel. Is there a place I can find documentation on this?

Comment: Seems like you have an OOM, Out Of Memory, situation and may be running out of swap space.  See http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html

Comment: Can you provide the out of memory error messages.

Comment: @DarkForce Part of the problem is that I don't get to see any error messages, because all of my processes are killed. Visually, the effect is that I'm logged out and cannot log back in. I'm only able to tell what is happening by leaving a root login running htop from a remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I like to have a record of solutions. The [article linked by sawdust](https://archive.li/yOBX6#selection-525.266-525.290) contains what I needed.

- The kernal activates the out-of-memory manager (mm/oom_kill.c in the Linux kernel) when it runs out of allocatable memory.
- The OOM manager uses some heuristics to determine which process should be killed. Total runtime of a process reduces the chance of death, while memory allocated increases it. There are other factors, but they don't matter for me.
- After picking a process, the OOM sends it SIGTERM.

There are two reasons for why, in my case, all processes *except* the one that's hogging the memory get killed.

1. My process ignores SIGTERM during the region where it is allocating memory. This might be because the process is actively receiving lots of other signals during this time, and/or because the process is blocking for I/O during much of the remaining time. In anycase, it ignores SIGTERM.
2. The process that is hogging all the memory typically has been running for a long time, accumulating RAM for a few hours. Even though it has about 4 times as much as any other process, it's long runtime (several hundred times longer than others) might cause the OOM manager to pick other processes to terminate first.

Solutions:

1. Running:

   ulimit -v memamount

for a particular user changes the maximum amount of memory the user can allocate with a single process to memamount. This can prevent the OOM manager from activating. Instead, malloc calls will fail, which I can detect.

2: Writing a handler for SIGTERM that gracefully cleans up might help, but only if the OOM is actually sending SIGTERM to the process, and the process is ignoring or failing to receive SIGTERM.

3: Set the memory limit from within your code (C):

```
//resource limit structure with both hard and soft max set to 2GB.
struct rlimit memmax; memmax.rlim_max=0x7FFFFFFF; memmax.rlim_cur = 0x7FFFFFFF;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK,&memmax); //set maximum virtual memory space to 2GB.
```

Comment: I'm going to leave the question open for a few days, and will accept any answer that can offer some extra detail or solutions. Or, if sawdust wants to write an answer, I can accept his too.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you have pin-pointed the root cause of the OOM.  You just have an explanation as to why processes are getting killed.  What about the root cause, rather than just avoid the symptoms?  One solution you seem to have overlooked is increasing the swap space.  Your system doesn't seem to be running out of virtual memory (i.e. getting any ENOMEM errors), and there's a lot of physical RAM.  So exactly how large is the swap space on the disk?  Consider making it 80GB or more, and then test if the problem reoccurs.

Comment: Further note: You actually need RLIMIT_AS, not RLIMIT_MEMLOCK.